# Search in other table and SUM with MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a table named ARTICLE with id, code and name.
I also have a other table named ORDER with id, article_code, qty.
I want to display a table with article_code, (ARTICLE.)name, qty.

I do this :

```
SELECT article_code, a.name, SUM(qty) AS quantity
FROM ORDER o
RIGHT JOIN ARTICLE a ON a.code = o.article_code
```

The problem is that there are duplicates in the ARTICLE table so I have as many SUM(qty) as duplicates. I tried `DISCTINCT(article_code)` or `GROUP BY article_code` but nothing.
But as soon as I remove the link with the table ARTICLE, it works.

How can I simply retrieve the name of each article, not taking into account the duplicate's number ?

Hope my message was clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try select using a select distinct  table alais

```
SELECT o.article_code, a.name, SUM(oqty) AS quantity
FROM ORDER o
RIGHT JOIN  (select distinct code, name  from article )  as a a ON a.code = o.article_code
```

Comment: Well I guess I have a lot of tricks to learn with SQL. It works perfectly, thank you.